# Loop for converting multiple files from csv.gz to csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, gzip

I have several csv.gzip files I am trying to convert and save to csv files. I'm able to do it for an individual file using:

```
with gzip.open('Pool.csv.gz') as f:
    Pool= pd.read_csv(f)
Pool.to_csv("Pool.csv")
```

I'm trying to create a loop to convert all files in directory but I'm failing. Here is my code:

```
import gzip
import glob
import os
os.chdir('/home/path')
extension = 'csv.gz'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
for i in range(len(all_filenames)):  gzip.open(i) as f:
    pool_1 = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: The `i` in `range` isn't a filename. Change to `all_filenames[i]`. And please indent the code correctly too, I think the line is messed up (with missing `with`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir()` to create your list of files and then loop through it:

```
import os
import gzip
import pandas as pd

dir_path = "/home/path"
all_files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if f.endswith('csv.gz')]

for file in all_files:
    with gzip.open(f"{dir_path}/{file}") as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        df.to_csv(f"{file.split('.')[0]}.csv")
```